# User can see protected pages after logging out

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, flask-login

One the home page, anonymous users can log in.

Once logged in, they can access protected content (returning a `401` for anonymous users).

However, when a user performs the following steps:

1. logging in
2. visiting a protected page
3. logging out
4. going back to the protected page (either by hitting the back button or by entering the address)

The now-anonymous user can still see the content of the protected page, with the data of the user with which he was logged in beforehand.

Funny thing is, this behaviour happens **only** in production environment (not on my local dev machine). In `dev`, everything behaves normally and once a user is logged out, he can't access protected content anymore. Which makes me guess it's not an application problem per se, but is rather on the level of `nginx` or `gunicorn`.

Any idea?

---

/application.py

```
from flask.ext.login import logout_user, login_required

# ...

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/me')
@login_required
def me():
    return render_template('me.html')
```

/templates/me.html

```
{{ current_user.name }}
<a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
```

Comment: How are you checking they are logged in? Cookie? / access token?  The back button may/may not issue a new request so they could be getting their local copy of the content, do you see a new request in the app when they do that?

Comment: I'm using `flask-login` which uses session and cookie data. It's supposed to delete all its cookies and session data upon logout, which he does perfectly in `dev` but doesn't seem to do in `prod`.

Comment: and after the logout in `prod`, if you use devtools/etc.. and look at your cookies are you still seeing the cookie? Are there any differences between dev/prod (ie use of SSL in prod, not in dev)

Comment: actually the problem in `prod` seems larger than that: when a user logs in, he is redirected to the home page... shown as an anonymous user. Only when he hits "refresh" does he see the "logged-in" homepage.

Comment: Put it simply, in `prod`, the user needs to "refresh" for the login/logout actions to be taken into account. Never noticed this kind of behaviour before.

Comment: Strangest thing is that I'm using `gunicorn` both in prod and in dev, with the same parameters. Only in prod I'm using `nginx` while in dev I'm hitting gunicorn directly.

Comment: Okay, more stuff. Whenever I'm on a particular page and I hit "enter" from the address bar (to reload the page), no request gets to the server. Only if I make a hard refresh is a requests sent. And while `/logout` redirects to `/` after having performed the logout, no new request is sent.

Comment: I'm gonna dive into `gunicorn`/`nginx` docs for this...

Comment: new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748206/nginx-does-not-receive-requests-except-for-hard-refresh

Comment: @Jivan You should update your question instead of leaving extra information in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in this other question I posted, related to the same topic:

[nginx does not receive requests except for hard refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748206/nginx-does-not-receive-requests-except-for-hard-refresh)

The problem was with `nginx` cache settings.

Adding `expires 0;` to `nginx.conf` in `http { ... }` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job,create a session cookie and a response object during login and identify user on the basis of the existence of the session cookie but when the user logout delete the session cookie.
Further this might help☺☺☺

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/