# nginx does not receive requests except for hard refresh

Tags: http, nginx, browser, digital-ocean

When doing a `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log` I notice the following things:

- when a user is on any page, and hits Enter from the address bar, no request is received by `nginx`, the browser directly loads from its cache instead
- when a user performs a hard refresh (F5 on Windows, Cmd+R on Mac), `nginx` did receive a request
- when a user visits `/login` which then redirects to `/`, `nginx` does indeed receive the request for `/login` but **not** for `/`, so the browser renders `/` from its cache, ignoring the fact that the user has been logged in since

Put it simply, the browsers doesn't send any request at all for already visited pages, except for hard refreshes performed by the user.

How could I make sure `nginx` receives all requests, since pages are dynamically generated and, for instance, home page content changes depending on the state of the user?

Using `nginx 1.9.3` on `digital ocean`'s `Ubuntu 15.10 x64` with `http`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `expires 0;` to `nginx.conf` in `http { }` did the trick.

Comment: i was going to suggest you look at caching / etag / headers next on your other question..